# Write simple logs using log4j 2

Tags: java, log4j2

I've looked everywhere but couldn't find any guides (that made sense to me) on how to use log4j 2. As a background, I'm extremely new to log4j or any type of logging, and the closest to logging I've ever gotten was System.out.println() or PrintWriter in Java (if that's even considered logging).

I went to [Apache Log4j 2 page](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html) to download the jar files, but there are 36 jar files and I have no clue which one to use.

Can anyone get me started on how to append simple String messages to a log file from my server code (in Java)? For instance, when a user connects to my server, I have a simple

```
System.out.println("user A connected to server at " + time);
```

code, which serves me no good during real usage. I'd like to replace all my System.out statements to logging using Log4j, so that I can read them later and detect any bugs/crashes in my server code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you read the page you linked?

Comment: It tells you exactly which of the 36 jar files to use.

Comment: Yes i did read the page. I guess I should've said "how to use them"

Answer (score 0):

Is this a webapp? In other words, does it have a WEB-INF folder? If so, create a simple log4j.properties file that contains something like:

```
# Define the root logger with appender file

log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=log.out

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

Make sure on this line:

```
log4j.appender.FILE.File=log.out
```

that you have a file actually created for it. I used log.out as an example.

Place this in your WEB-INF folder.

If it's a Maven project, find a place in your project for the file and add it manually by right clicking Run->Run Configuration -> [classpath tab] -> click on user Entries -> Advanced -> Select Add Folder -> and adding the directory where you put the file.

In your class, import:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.FileAppender;
```

Then instantiate your logger object:

```
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LdapPurge.class.getName());
```

Try that and see if it works.

Comment: That's old-school Log4J configuration.  This is a Log4J2 installation.

Comment: the lines:
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.FileAppender;
are giving me compile error. Perhaps its because I'm trying to use version 2?

Comment: It probably is. I overlooked that you were using L4J2. If the import is giving you an error, it will usually tell you if the jar you are importing exists in the project or not. I really only have experience with the original Log4J.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with Log4j version 2.x and recently wrote a post about its use. You can review it, maybe it will help you:

To use Log4j 2.x 2 libraries are required:

```
<dependency>
             <groupId> org.apache.logging.log4j </groupId>
             <artifactId> log4j-core </artifactId>
             <version> 2.8.2 </version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
             <groupId> org.apache.logging.log4j </groupId>
             <artifactId> log4j-api </artifactId>
             <version> 2.8.2 </version>
</dependency>
```

Create the log42.xml file in the resources folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html-->
<Configuration status="TRACE" monitorInterval="30">
  <!-- The properties that are needed in the configuration of the appenders are defined | property definition -->
 <Properties>
    <!--The pattern is defined. For writing in logs -->
  <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Property>
  <!--Storage location is defined -->
 <Property name="APP_LOG_ROOT">var/log/tomcat0</Property>
 </Properties>
  <Appenders>
   <!-- Configuration for writing events to console (cmd, ide, terminal)-->
   <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
      <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
   </Console>
   <!-- 
    Configuration for writing debug events.
    for more information about properties: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html
    -->
   <RollingFile name="debugLog" 
    fileName="${APP_LOG_ROOT}/logs/automatizador-debug.log" 
    filePattern="${APP_LOG_ROOT}/logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/automatizador-debug-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
    <LevelRangeFilter minLevel="DEBUG" maxLevel="DEBUG" onMatch="ACCEPT" 
     onMismatch="DENY"/>
    <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
    <Policies>
     <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
     <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="19500KB" />
    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
   </RollingFile>
    <!--Define the logger-->
    <Loggers>
        <!--only log events from type "debug" for the package: com.advanced.development -->
        <Logger name="com.advanced.development" additivity="false" 
            level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="debugLog"  />
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"  />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="debugLog"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

For more details: https://su9.co/9BaE74E

Comment: Please explain this answer better. The xml code seems out of context. Your linked blog post suggests (in Spanish) that the code should go into some file `log4j2-spring.xml`. Please include all relevant information in your answer. Links as sources are fine, but your answer should be complete without them.

Comment: Adjustment made.